# Mobile Controls for asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am looking for a standard suite of controls in ASP.NET(Visual Studio 2008 and later) that are compatible for mobile web browsing. Is there any suite provided by Microsoft or community specifically for Mobile Web Application/Site Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out the [Creating ASP.NET Mobile Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8htez1ds.aspx) write-up? It contains a list of [mobile controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08e3b0ck.aspx).

- AdRotator
- Calendar
- Command
- CompareValidator
- CustomValidator
- Form
- Image
- Label
- Link
- List
- MobilePage
- ObjectList
- Panel
- PhoneCall
- RangeValidator
- RegularExpressionValidator
- RequiredFieldValidator
- SelectionList
- StyleSheet
- TextBox
- TextView
- ValidationSummary

All part fo the `System.Web.UI.MobileControls` namespace (as opposed to the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace)

Also, see [asp.net/mobile](http://www.asp.net/mobile)